# Can you match unicode blocks by name in vim?

Tags: regular-expression, search, unicode, escape

```
\p{Cyrillic}
```

Works in my normal regular expressions. When trying to match in Vim or gvim however, I can not seem to get it to work.

I tried something like this:

```
\p\{Cyrillic}
```

Is it not supported, or am I missing something?

Comment: paste the actual text that you want to match with regexp pattern.

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim has its own regex engine and it doesn't support `{Cyrillic}`.

You probably want to read [`:h pattern-atoms`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#pattern-atoms) and [`:h /character-classes`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2fcharacter-classes) to find out what you can use in your regexes.

I think the best alternative you can find comes from [`:h /[]`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5b%5d) (especially the last example):

```
\_[]
    A collection.  This is a sequence of characters enclosed in brackets.
    It matches any single character in the collection.

    Example     matches ~
    [xyz]       any 'x', 'y' or 'z'
    [a-zA-Z]$   any alphabetic character at the end of a line
    [А-яЁё]     Russian alphabet (with utf-8 and cp1251)
```